# Mysql Bad Query performance with many joins

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a query that takes minutes to execute on a small data set, what is the problem? here is the  explain output:

```
id  select_type table           type    possible_keys               key                 key_len   ref             rows  Extra

1   SIMPLE      BT_CALL_CLASS.. const   PRIMARY                     PRIMARY             4         const           1     Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      BT_FLAGS_FLAGS  const   PRIMARY                     PRIMARY             4         const           1     Using index
1   SIMPLE      BT_DIRECTORY... range   PRIMARY                     PRIMARY             4         NULL            308   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE      BT_CALL_FLAGS.. ref     PRIMARY,FKDF68A2ED9F150002  FKDF68A2ED9F150002  4         const           49    Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE      BT_DEPARTMENT.. index   PRIMARY                     FK1F3A276188DDBD3   5         NULL            27    Using where; Using index; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE      BT_USERS_USER.. index   PRIMARY                     FK6A68E086C27A155   5         NULL            233   Using where; Using index; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE      BT_FCT_CALLS..  eq_ref  PRIMARY,FKDF68A2ED4F28..    PRIMARY             8         ...call_id      1     Using where
```

The query

```
 desc SELECT DISTINCT 
      BT_FCT_CALLS_FCT_CALLS.start_time AS COL0
     ,BT_FCT_CALLS_FCT_CALLS.calling_number AS COL1
     ,BT_FCT_CALLS_FCT_CALLS.called_number AS COL2
     ,BT_FCT_CALLS_FCT_CALLS.response AS COL3

 FROM departments BT_DEPARTMENTS_DEPARTMENTS_3 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 ( 
  directory_numbers BT_DIRECTORY_NUMBERS_DIRECTORY_NUMBERS LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  ( 
   users BT_USERS_USERS_2 JOIN 
   ( 
    call_classification_dim BT_CALL_CLASSIFICATION_DIM_CALL_CLASSIFICATION_DIM JOIN 
    ( 
     flags BT_FLAGS_FLAGS JOIN 
     ( 
      fct_calls BT_FCT_CALLS_FCT_CALLS JOIN call_flags BT_CALL_FLAGS_CALL_FLAGS
      ON ( BT_FCT_CALLS_FCT_CALLS.id = BT_CALL_FLAGS_CALL_FLAGS.call_id )
     ) 
     ON ( BT_CALL_FLAGS_CALL_FLAGS.flag = BT_FLAGS_FLAGS.id AND (  BT_FLAGS_FLAGS.id  = 1 )  )
    ) 
    ON ( BT_FCT_CALLS_FCT_CALLS.call_direction_id = BT_CALL_CLASSIFICATION_DIM_CALL_CLASSIFICATION_DIM.id AND (  BT_CALL_CLASSIFICATION_DIM_CALL_CLASSIFICATION_DIM.id  = 2 )  )
   ) 
   ON ( (( BT_FCT_CALLS_FCT_CALLS.on_network_called_user_id  =  BT_USERS_USERS_2.id ) OR ( BT_FCT_CALLS_FCT_CALLS.on_network_calling_user_id  =  BT_USERS_USERS_2.id )) AND TRUE   )
  ) 
  ON ( (( BT_FCT_CALLS_FCT_CALLS.on_network_called_ext_id  =  BT_DIRECTORY_NUMBERS_DIRECTORY_NUMBERS.id ) OR ( BT_FCT_CALLS_FCT_CALLS.on_network_calling_ext_id  =  BT_DIRECTORY_NUMBERS_DIRECTORY_NUMBERS.id )) AND TRUE )
 ) 
 ON ( (( BT_FCT_CALLS_FCT_CALLS.on_network_called_department_id  =  BT_DEPARTMENTS_DEPARTMENTS_3.id ) OR ( BT_FCT_CALLS_FCT_CALLS.on_network_calling_department_id  =  BT_DEPARTMENTS_DEPARTMENTS_3.id )) AND TRUE )

  WHERE 
    (
      (
          NOT( BT_DEPARTMENTS_DEPARTMENTS_3.id  IN ( 1 ) )
      )
  AND (
          NOT( BT_DIRECTORY_NUMBERS_DIRECTORY_NUMBERS.id  IN ( 1 ) )
      )

  AND (
          NOT( BT_USERS_USERS_2.id  IN ( 1 ) )
      )
    )
ORDER BY 
      COL0
```

Comment: There could be many explanations (indexes, join, ...) and it's quite impossible to tell without getting to see the query. Even then it could be tricky...

Comment: The problem is we don't have the query.

Comment: Do you have indexes ? I go with Bartdude in general.

Comment: wh< do you have join inside a join ?

Comment: This is a computer-generated query I don't have much control over it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment the queries are auto-generated and I can't modify them much, anyways, after an upgrade to mysql 5.6.14 ,and with no change what so ever to the query itself, the performance became normal (compared to other queries with similar complexity)!

Answer (score 0):

To start with change your WHERE clause to:

```
 WHERE 
 BT_DEPARTMENTS_DEPARTMENTS_3.id  <> 1 AND 
 BT_DIRECTORY_NUMBERS_DIRECTORY_NUMBERS.id  <> 1 AND 
 BT_USERS_USERS_2.id <> 1
```

It's faster than using NOT IN(..)

Remove the `AND TRUE` it's not needed.

Comment: True but still is not what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets start with the very poorly written flow of the query.  By simplifying the immediate relationships vs all your nesting can help clear some things up.  Second, show the relationship down the tree that things are related.  You are bouncing all over.  I've also shortened the "aliases" for readability. Finally, you don't need all the tables as you are not getting values from all the tables which is making many things useless.  Anyhow, here is a cleaned-up version of your original query.  As you can see, much easier to see where table A links to B links to C links to D etc.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      calls.start_time AS COL0,
      calls.calling_number AS COL1,
      calls.called_number AS COL2,
      calls.response AS COL3
   FROM 
      fct_calls calls 
         JOIN departments dpt3 
            ON calls.on_network_called_department_id = dpt3.id
            OR calls.on_network_calling_department_id = dpt3.id
         JOIN users u2 
            ON calls.on_network_called_user_id = u2.id
            OR calls.on_network_calling_user_id = u2.id
         JOIN directory_numbers dirNums 
            ON calls.on_network_called_ext_id = dirNums.id 
            OR calls.on_network_calling_ext_id = dirNums.id 
         JOIN call_classification_dim classDim 
            ON calls.call_direction_id = classDim.id 
            AND classDim.id = 2
         JOIN call_flags callFlags
            ON calls.id = callFlags.call_id
            JOIN flags f 
               ON callFlags.flag = f.id 
               AND f.id = 1
  WHERE
         dpt3.id <> 1
     AND dirNums.id <> 1
     AND  u2.id = 1
  ORDER BY 
     COL0
```

Now, here is what I would run with.  Again, so many things are not even being used, such as call flags and directory numbers.  Start with all calls that have the user ID you are interested in via either calling or called position.  I would have an index on the calls table on ( on_network_called_user_id, on_network_calling_user_id ).  I would assume the other tables have indexes on their respective primary "ID" columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      calls.start_time AS COL0,
      calls.calling_number AS COL1,
      calls.called_number AS COL2,
      calls.response AS COL3
   FROM 
      fct_calls calls 
         JOIN departments dpt3 
            ON calls.on_network_called_department_id = dpt3.id
            OR calls.on_network_calling_department_id = dpt3.id
         JOIN directory_numbers dirNums 
            ON calls.on_network_called_ext_id = dirNums.id 
            OR calls.on_network_calling_ext_id = dirNums.id 
  WHERE
     (    calls.on_network_called_user_id = 1
       OR calls.on_network_calling_user_id = 1 )
     AND dpt3.id <> 1
     AND dirNums.id <> 1
  ORDER BY 
     COL0
```

Taking it a step further, you MIGHT get better performance by doing a UNION due to the consideration of either calling or being called, you could try the following.  So you are looking for any call where the person DOING the calling is user ID 1 AND the department called is NOT 1 and the directory extension is NOT 1... Or, user ID 1 is BEING called, but ignore those from dept 1 and extension 1.

I would have TWO indexes on the calls table for
This one for who IS BEING CALLED, and WHERE THAT CALL ORIGINATED FROM
(on_network_called_user_id, on_network_calling_department_id, on_network_calling_ext_id )
This the reverse... who IS CALLING, and WHAT Department/Extension are they calling
(on_network_calling_user_id, on_network_called_department_id, on_network_called_ext_id)

```
SELECT
      calls.start_time AS COL0,
      calls.calling_number AS COL1,
      calls.called_number AS COL2,
      calls.response AS COL3
   FROM 
      fct_calls calls 
         LEFT JOIN departments dpt3 
            OR calls.on_network_calling_department_id = dpt3.id
         LEFT JOIN directory_numbers dirNums 
            OR calls.on_network_calling_ext_id = dirNums.id 
   WHERE
          calls.on_network_called_user_id = 1
      AND calls.on_network_calling_department_id <> 1
      AND calls.on_network_calling_ext_id <> 1
   ORDER BY 
      COL0
UNION
SELECT
      calls.start_time AS COL0,
      calls.calling_number AS COL1,
      calls.called_number AS COL2,
      calls.response AS COL3
   FROM 
      fct_calls calls 
         LEFT JOIN departments dpt3 
            OR calls.on_network_called_department_id = dpt3.id
         LEFT JOIN directory_numbers dirNums 
            OR calls.on_network_called_ext_id = dirNums.id 
   WHERE
          calls.on_network_calling_user_id = 1
      AND calls.on_network_called_department_id <> 1
      AND calls.on_network_called_ext_id <> 1
```